# BigQuery select rows with two (or more / less) matches in a repeated field

Tags: google-bigquery, unnest

I am having a schema that looks like:

```
[
    {
        "name": "name",
        "type": "STRING",
        "mode": "REQUIRED"
    },
    {
        "name": "frm",
        "type": "RECORD",
        "mode": "REPEATED",
        "fields": [
            {
                "name": "c",
                "type": "STRING",
                "mode": "REQUIRED"
            },
            {
                "name": "n",
                "type": "STRING",
                "mode": "REQUIRED"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "name": "",
        "type": "STRING",
        "mode": "NULLABLE"
    }
]
```

With a sample record that looks like this:

[image]

I am trying to write a query that selects this row when there is a row in `frm` that matches `C = 'X'` and another row that has `C = 'Z'`. Only when both conditions are true, I would love to select the "name" of the parent row. I actually have no clue how I could achieve this. Any suggestions?

E.g. this works, but I am unnesting `frm` two times, there must a more efficient way I guess.

```
SELECT name FROM `t2`
WHERE 'X' in UNNEST(frm.c) AND 'Y' in UNNEST(frm.c)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider below approach

```
select name
from your_table t
where 2 = (
  select count(distinct c)
  from t.frm
  where c in ('X', 'Z')
)
```